# how to get the desired output by executing below function

Tags: sql-server

My question is I wrote a function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].StringSplitting_23012012 (@string NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Delimiter NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS
 @Temp TABLE (string NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @p int
   SET @p = 0
   --SET @string = (@string + @Delimiter)
   WHILE charindex(@Delimiter,@string) < 0 --,@p) <> 0 
     BEGIN
       INSERT into @Temp
       SELECT substring(@string,@p,charindex(@Delimiter,@string)) --+ @p)
       --select   substring(@string,5,15) SET @p = charindex(@Delimiter,@string) --1
     END
   RETURN
END
```

and passing the string to that function

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].StringSplitting('SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1999 QTY1:
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P12-2999 QTY2 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY3 : 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY4 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P59-5999 QTY5 : 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY6 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P79-7999 QTY7 : 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY8',':')
```

and I am getting the output as

```
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1999 QTY1
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P12-2999 QTY2 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY3   
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY4 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P59-5999 QTY5 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY6 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P79-7999 QTY7 
SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY8
```

up to this it is ok but i need the output like

```
SPLA P12-2999 QTY2 
SPLA P19-1399 QTY3   
SPLA P19-1399 QTY4 
SPLA P59-5999 QTY5 
SPLA P69-6999 QTY6 
SPLA P79-7999 QTY7 
SPLA P69-6999 QTY8
```

would u please help me out how to write function or procedure to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function - like so:

[Formatted for clarity]

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].StringSplitting(
REPLACE('SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1999 QTY1:
         SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P12-2999 QTY2 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY3 : 
         SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY4 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P59-5999 QTY5 : 
         SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY6 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P79-7999 QTY7 : 
         SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY8', '-WINSVRSTD #','')
,':')
```

[for copy-and-paste]

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].StringSplitting(REPLACE(
'SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1999 QTY1 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P12-2999 QTY2 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY3 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P19-1399 QTY4 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P59-5999 QTY5 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY6 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P79-7999 QTY7 : SPLA-WINSVRSTD #P69-6999 QTY8'
, '-WINSVRSTD #','') ,':')
```